# Catching Invalid Input of a Text Box and Using a custom converter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters

I'm currently createing a WPF User Interface in C# with a textbox for the German Market.

I created a Data binding between the Text Box text and the Double Value.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Length, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

If I enter "10.4" it will save the double value 10,4

If I enter "10,4" it will save the double value 104.0

If I enter "asd" it will not save anything, but put a red highlight around the textbox.

I would like the box to accept both ways "," and "."  and treat them equally.

Therefore  I used a converter
(which I got from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/b3a5a9ba-0ebe-4a8a-9e34-f32e9545c941/kommazahlen-im-datagrid)

Adding `Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter}, ConverterCulture=de-de,` to the XAML

```
public class DoubleConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Member

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return double.Parse(value.ToString().Replace(",", "."), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The "," and "." issue is now solved, but the behaviour in the "asd" case has changed. I get an exception and the red square is gone.

How can I combine these two behaviours?

Thanks
Karl

Comment: Have you tried setting the `BorderThickness="0.99"`. I know I had similar issue and when I changed the mentioned borderThickness I got the red outline. HTH

Comment: Did you try to set [validation rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule.aspx)? Specifically `ExceptionValidationRule` will cause red border to appears when bound property setter `throw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = value.ToString().Replace(",", "."), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double number;
bool result = Double.TryParse(input , out number);
if (result)
{
    return number;         
}
else
{
    return input;
}
```